# Bison, flex simple calculator

Tags: calculator, bison

I want to make parser for simple calculator.

The input format is like "10+20;", "50*60;","4+8;1-7;"

The output should be 30 3000 12 -6

Each case ending always has a semicolon";"

My bison file looks like this

```
%{  
#include <stdio.h> 
extern FILE* yyin;
%}

%token T_NUM

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%% 

S   :   S E '\n'        { printf("ans = %d\n", $2); }
    |   /* empty */     { /* empty */ }
    ;

E   :   E '+' E        { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    |   E '-' E         { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    |   E '*' E         { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    |   E '/' E         { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    |   T_NUM           { $$ = $1; }
    |   '(' E ')'       { $$ = $2; }
    ;

%%          
yyerror (char *s)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);  
}
yywrap()    
{
   return (1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   yyin = fopen("testcase.in", "r");    
   yyparse();   
   fclose(yyin);
   return 0;
}
```

Flex  file looks like this:

```
%{ 
#include "cal.tab.h"
%}

%% 
[0-9]+          { yylval = atoi(yytext); return T_NUM; }
[-/+*()\n]      { return yytext[0]; }
[ \t]           { }

[;]             { }
.               { return 0; /* end when meet everything else */ }
%%
```

The testcase.in looks like this

34+801;

1+2;

2+3;2+4;

3/2;3*5;

The ./a.out should be like

835

3

5

6

1

15

But my result is "syntax error"

Hope you can help me.plz~

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your program; all the pieces are there. You just need to respect your own problem description and write your scanner and parser to use semicolon as a terminator instead of newline.

You claim that you want expressions to be terminated by semicolons, and your example input has that format. But your scanner ignores semicolons, and your grammar requires that expressions be terminated with newline characters. You need to ignore newlines, and requires expressions to be terminated by semicolons:

```c
/* In cal.y, line 6 */
S   :   S E ';'        { printf("ans = %d\n", $2); }
/*           ^
 *           |--------- Changed semicolon to newline.
 */

/* In cal.l, lines 7-8. Lines 9 and 10 removed. */
[-/+*();]       { return yytext[0]; }
 /*    ^
  *    |-------- Changed newline to semicolon.
  */
[ \t\n]         { }
 /*  ^
  *  |-----------Changed semicolon to newline.
  */
```

Answer (score -1):

change `S E '\n'` to `E ';' S` because every expression ends with a semicolon. Note (from @rici comment) that an alternative rule would be: `S: S ';' E`. Each rule will cause a different resulting [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for you to scan later. Choose the one that fits your needs better.

Comment: You definitely do not want a right-recursive production there; it will result in very confusing output. Also, if you look at the sample input, you'll see that it's not the case that "every expression is in a separate line". Several lines have multiple expressions.

Comment: Thanks @rici, I edited the post. I personally think that both resulting AST's are equivalent. as a matter of taste I like a list with a `1-item-head ++ rest` over `all-but-last ++ 1-item-last`

Comment: semicolon is used as a terminator, not a seperator, so the rule should be `S : S E ';'`